# Split a Tensorflow dataset by class label

Tags: tensorflow, filter, split, dataset

I have a tensorflow dataset that I created with the following function: dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((imgs, labels)). My labels are "0" and "1" and I would like to split this dataset into two, one with all entries that have a label "0" and one with all entries that have a label "1". I have been trying to find a way to do this using the .filter function but to no avail. Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Filter will work.

```
dataset_zero = dataset.filter(lambda image, label: label == 0)
dataset_one = dataset.filter(lambda image, label: label == 1)
```

Dataset's stream based operations are annoying though. If your dataset is small, consider retrieving the dataset as a list/numpy array using Dataset.as_numpy_iterator and just using fancy indexing to get your zeros and ones.